# How does Thanos do this using Nebula's beacon?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, how does Thanos travel to the future using Nebula's beacon?

Does he have people experienced in quantum physics or some magic stone/equipment which can enable time travel of such a large scale army?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How did Nebula do it?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99669/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson BTW didn't knew we're not supposed to post spoilers in  question title. Is there a feature to hide the title under spoiler tag?

Comment: No, just invest some work into a reasonable but still informative title. It's usually not too hard to come up with a rephrasal. For what it's worth, the title of this question seems fine.